# Stop filebeat after ingesting all the logs

Tags: logstash, filebeat

I have observed that filebeat runs forever after ingestion of all the logs.

Is there any way through which filebeat will auto stop after the all logs are ingested?
Is the configuration below is correct or not ?

```
filebeat.prospectors:
    shutdown_timeout: 0s
    enabled: true
    paths:
    - D:\new.log

    output.logstash:
    hosts: "localhost:5044"
```

[image]

I do not find anything in the logstash documentation to help me on this question.

Comment: It's the normal behavior of filebeat. The [shutdown_timeout](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/6.2/configuration-general-options.html#shutdown-timeout) is not relevant to your goal, it is only used when filebeat is shutting down and does not cause filebeat to shut down. You'll have to use an external mechanism to shut down filebeat.

Comment: what is that external mechanism

Comment: You'll have to find one. It is against what filebeat is designed for, so maybe it's not the right tool for the job.

Comment: how to know all the data is parsed or not??

Comment: Perhaps with the [registry file](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/6.2/migration-registry-file.html). Or by looking at the message received by logstash.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use client_inactivity_timeout => "30" in the input section of logstash.conf file.

hope this helps.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-beats.html#plugins-inputs-beats-client_inactivity_timeout